# How would you solve this SQL writing problem in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

How would you solve this SQL writing problem in C#?

I'm using a data poller which retrieves data from an API every minutes.
What I'm doing is that I'm going to take these data and write it to a table in my SQL. The data from the API are like a feed. There are times where new items in the feed is added, and sometime the feed are still the same.

My problem now is that I retrieve the feed from the API each minute and send it to the database, but what I want to achieve is to only send the data table to the database if there actually has been some changes or new elements has been added since last time I retrieved feed from the API.

How would you solve this? The reason I want to solve this, is because I don't want to overkill the DB with post request

Comment: We love that you're here and we want to help you with code you have written. Show us where you're stuck.

Comment: It's best to do this at the db level: send the data to a stored procedure which can check and if not exist, it will insert. Simple.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @CodingYoshi but if the item already exist with same values, is it just going to skip it? :) I want to insert if it doesn't exist, update if it exist and the object doesn't have the same values, or skip if they are the same.

Would sending data tables like this to the database each minute cause bad performance to the database?

Comment: To check, if something has changed, so you can update the values, will require even more processing. For this, you will need some modification timestamp, if you wish to do it efficiently.

Comment: In the stored procedure do an insert or if exist do an update. Search for *Upsert* online. Performance: Don't worry about it. Do it. Use it and if performance is bad and you know for certain it is this part of your application which is the bottleneck, then do something about it. Otherwise, you're good to go.

Comment: If you gave us more details about your actual feed, we could give you some more relevant advice. Currently, it's pretty much guesswork, since we don't know, if there are ids, some sort of modification date, or some other option for implementing incremental imports. I have had to do this for various APIs, and every one has their own methods for doing things optimally.

Comment: There are IDs which can be lookup! Status right now is; 40 objects on API1 , 4 objects on API 2 and API 3 has 17 elements.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data feed. The best option would be, if your feed offers the ability to fetch only new item since some point in time (incremental imports). If this is not possible, you should have some identifier for your items. You could then check, if an id is already present in your database. If it is already present, skip the entry. If not, send the whole entry to your database. If you also don't have any sort of identifier, you're most likely out of luck.

Comment: The feed API offers to fetch data 1 day back. 
But does this mean that I should retrieve the data from the database, to check if it already exist? I want to lessen the workload on the database. Is it possible to save the data to some interface class called oldData, then fetch the data from API and compare with oldData from the previous retrieval from API, if new item doesn't exist in the oldData, it will be added to the datable, or else it will add the updated data to the datable?

Comment: You could do something like `SELECT Id FROM MyData WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` where `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` would be the ids you got from your call to the api. Then, you can just check the ids you get back from the DB. Those you get back are already there, the others must be inserted.

Comment: But is this going to have any impact with the performance of the database?  By doing this many retrieval every minutes? :)

Comment: It is not many retrievals, it is just one query. If you did one select for each id, that would of course have an impact on your performance. One select with all ids is no problem. However, what amount of data are we talking about? SQL Server only supports up to 2100 variables in one query. If your feed give you more data than that, things can get ugly.

Comment: There are IDs which can be lookup! Status right now is; 40 objects on API1 , 4 objects on API 2 and API 3 has 17 elements.

It could fetch for an hour and it would still be the same elements, it's just sometimes a new item is added in the API.